# Как отобразить в ограниченном по высоте div, другой div, по вертикали, вне свойства overflow-x: auto;

Tags: css, веб-программирование, html5, frontend, sass

**Всем привет, нужна помощь! Есть код:**

```html
<html>

<head>
    <style>
        .container {
            display: flex;
            background-color: yellowgreen;
            width: 200px;
            overflow-x: auto;
        }
        
        .day {
            padding: 10px;
            background-color: red;
        }
        
        .poi-container {
            position: relative;
            width: 0px;
            height: 0px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class='container'>
        <div class='day'>234</div>
        <div class='day'>234</div>
        <div class='day'>234</div>
        <div class='day'>234</div>
        <div class='day'><span>234</span>
            <div class='poi-container'>
                <div>У каждой юной пони</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class='day'>234</div>
        <div class='day'>234</div>
        <div class='day'>234</div>
        <div class='day'>234</div>
        <div class='day'>234</div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Есть `<div class='container'>` в длинной авто, высотой 50px и свойством `overflow-x: scroll.` В нем лежат `<div class='day'>DAY1</div>` и внутри них лежат еще `<div class='poi-container'>`. 
Свойство `overflow-x: auto` сворачивает контейнер по высоте в 50px, а нужно чтобы горизонтальный скролл был, а вертикальный нет, чтобы `<div class='poi-container'>` был всегда видимый, не прятался в скролл. Высоту контейнера в 50px измениться нельзя, она обязана быть такой по множеству причин. Помогите!!!!

Comment: то есть вы хотите в блок высотой 50px, засунуть блок высотой в 100px? Так не будет! Либо height:auto;, либо скрол вертикальный.

Comment: Без свойства overflow все отлично отображается у меня. Даже за пределы div, просто ищу способ как показать информацию за пределы скролла.

Comment: position:absolute для блока второго, не пробовали?

Comment: Использовал позиционирование, не помогло. Игрался и с overflow: visible, безрезультатно.

Comment: посмотрите тут! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4605715/position-absolute-and-overflow-hidden

Comment: @StanislauDushkevich Не совсем понятно, чего вы собственно пытаетесь добиться. Если хотите просто отключить вертикальный скролл, то для контейнера задайте overflow-y: hidden.

Comment: @Hikikomori да, примерно, только не совсем отключить, а все что скрывается в вертикальный скролл сделать постоянно видимым на экране, а горизонтальный скролл чтобы скроллится. Запустите мой код выше. "У каждой пони" должен вылезать за пределы контейнера, вертикальный скролл вообще не должен отображаться. Вот цель.

Comment: @SergeyB не работает позиционирование в этой задаче, увы :(

Comment: нашол решение для вашей задачи, посмотрите здесьhttps://css-tricks.com/popping-hidden-overflow/

Comment: @SergeyB увы, но нет, это не решение:(
Не помогает в данном случае:(